# Setting up port redirection on Windows Server 2012 in Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, windows-server-2012-r2, netsh

I have a couple of servers in amazon EC2

- One server is a Windows Server 2012, is used to host a web application, there is an elastic ip address attached to this server.
- The second server is a linux server, to host the database, this server do not have a public ip address, this database server only listen using private network interface.

I need to expose the database server through web server, I mean, I like to connect to a particular port in windows server and create a port forwarding to reach linux server.

I tried to use this command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 listenport=4638
connectaddress=172.30.10.70 connectport=3306
```

Locally, in windows server, I cant connect to mysql server using the windows server private address and port 4638, I can run queries without problems.

The problem is when I try to connect using the attached elastic ip address, I cannot reach mysql server, the port 4638 is opened in the Windows server security group.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled IPv6?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555744

If yes, re installing it might work.

Try running wireshark on Win server to see what happens with those packets.

Comment: This answer is for Windows XP, the servers are running windows server 2012